# Changing column values to lower case using .loc in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been searching to change the value of a column of a dataframe to lowercase using .loc but got none.
Any example would be great!

I want to lowercase my name column -

```
df.loc[:, "name"] = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not covert the Series:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.lower()
```

using loc:

```
df.loc[:,'name'] = df.loc[:, 'name'].str.lower()
```

Comment: I tried that but its giving some kind of warning -
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @RahulSyal see the edit using `.loc`. I think it is peculiar that the first line throws a warning. It does not do that when I execute the code on my machine.

Comment: The error appears because the dataframe needs to be copied earlier in the code. e.g. if you have some earlier code like `df = df[df['col'] != 'foo']` then you can try to set `df = df[df['col'] != 'foo'].copy()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.str.` methods to convert a column to lowercase:

`df["name"].str.lower()`

And then to overwrite the original:

`df.loc[:,"name"] = df.loc[:,"name"].str.lower()`

Using `.loc` to reassign prevents the pink warning about writing to copies of slices.

The `.str.` tells Pandas that you want to treat the column as a collection of strings, applying a string method to each one, rather than viewing it simply as a series (that happens to contain strings).

Comment: When we are converting a column to lowecase - please remove dot("."), It should be df["name"] not df.["name"] and yes we can directly overwrite the original, Thanks .

Comment: Good spot - I'll fix the typo.